# Arduino IDE avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

Tags: upload, arduino, ide, port, avrdude

So I bought myself an ArduCAM ESP8266 UNO V2. At the beginning I was able to upload the code to my board, but now it gives me an error:

```
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
```

I have windows 7 pro x64

Any ideas to what seems to be the problem?

I have tried:

1. checking ports
2. reinstalling drivers
3. tryed other computer
4. updating java
5. reseting
6. different boards in arduino IDE
7. restarting computer
8. safe mode
9. Different USB holes
10. Different USB cables
    [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good day everyone. The solution turned out to be easier than i tought. Dont forget you have to install add-on-packages from http://www.arducam.com/arducam-esp8266-uno-board-arduino-camera/ so Arduino IDE software recognises your ArduCAM board.

File>Preferences Add http://www.arducam.com/downloads/ESP8266_UNO/package_ArduCAM_index.json to the box shown below.

[image: Add]

Tools > Board > Board Manager

[image]

Now install ArduCAM add-on-package

[image]